# How do access a json object 0 using a javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I pretend to do console.log of the holidays variable appear in the list and not as an array. How do I get this information as a simple object?

My json:

```
[{
    "2016-10-10":[{"name":"Columbus Day","country":"US","date":"2016-10-10"}],
    "2016-10-31":[{"name":"Halloween","country":"US","date":"2016-10-31"}]
}]
```

My app:

```
app.factory('calendario', function($http) {    
    return{
        getJobs : function() {
            return $http({
                url: '/app/components/home/controller/test_calendar.json',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
    }     
});
```

controller:

```
    var holidays = [];

    calendario.getJobs().success(function(data){
        holidays.push(data[0]);
    }); 

    $scope.setDayContent = function(date) {

        console.log(holidays);

};
```

Example:

I want this

[image]

I don't want this

[image]

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Remove the `[` and `]` from the beginning and end.

Comment: @Andreas While that article is technically correct, for normal conversation the term "JSON Object" is well understood.

Comment: I want this in my output Object {2016-10-09: Array[1], 2016-10-10: Array[1], 2016-10-31: Array[1], 2016-11-08: Array[2], 2016-11-11: Array[1]…}

Comment: i continue don't understand Andreas sory

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not allowed to point out the wrong technical term. Good to know...

Comment: @Andreas I never said that. I'm just pointing out that most developers aren't going to balk at the term JSON Object.

Comment: What console are you using? It seems to have extremely archaic formatting which does not print the object like a modern browser. Look into getting a better console.

Comment: i will put image what i want

Comment: i update my doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to flatten it, so, Nick is right, do not use the array, use dict/hash instead. In case your functionality will suffer you can use some workaround:

```
var holidays = [{
    "2016-10-10":[{"name":"Columbus Day","country":"US","date":"2016-10-10"}],
    "2016-10-31":[{"name":"Halloween","country":"US","date":"2016-10-31"}]
    }];
var flatten_holidays = holidays.reduce(function(elem){return elem});
```

I do not feel like it is specifically AngularJS question, more like common JavaScript instead.
For your example it would be:

```
var holidays = [];

calendario.getJobs().success(function(data){
    holidays.push(data[0]);
}); 

$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
    console.log(holidays.reduce(function(elem){return elem}));
};
```

or, if the preference is to use dict/hash:

```
var holidays = {};

calendario.getJobs().success(function(data){ 
//if data is: {"2016-10-10":[{"name":"Columbus day","country":"US","date":"2016-10-10"}]}
var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
var value = data[key];
holidays[key] = value;
}); 

$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
    console.log(holidays);
};
```

Comment: the dict/hash work well but he return as the 2 image in my example
I need the first image but your example is good i will try with your example

Comment: Inside the calendar function works fine but when i call the var holidays in the 2 function returns as object

Comment: According to the image of expected output you have provided - object is what you wanted to get. If not - please give more details.

Comment: I put my app but i think it does not make much difference

Comment: `var flatten_holidays = holidays.reduce(function(elem){return elem});` is useless.... literally it is just `var flatten_holidays = holidays[0];`

Comment: the console was undefined

Comment: @epascarello, yes it does the same here, the only reason I suggested this - in comments to Nick's answer, Jose mentioned that `data[0]` does not work for him for some reasons.

Comment: is true the [0] doesn't work for me idk and reduce say i can't have a reduce with a value null but i have one object -.-'

Comment: for example when i use the console in my calendario i have the first image when i use  the console in my $scope.setDatContent i have the second image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a list use a map

```
holidays = {}
```

Then put the items in the map with key the date and value the array:

```
holidays[data[0].date] = data[0].days;
```

But it looks like you already have the map, so probably you can just save data directly instead of pushing it in a list:

```
var holidays = {};

calendario.getJobs().success(function(data){
    holidays=data;
}); 

$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
  console.log(holidays);
};
```

Comment: but my problem is [0] doesn't work for me i dont know. Probably is array is different of object no?

Comment: What does it do if you take my code but without the [0]? I think that might be what you need then. Can you paste me that output?

Comment: See my example of the images that I intend. But yes you are right

Comment: I saw the images. Is it solved with leaving the [0] out?  (I edited my code snippet). Can you paste the result of that?

Comment: The reason you have the list is because you declare holidays as a list using [] and you push your data in the list. If you just use a variable as a map using {} and leave the variable alone with holidays = data; i think it will be okay

Comment: sory for the delay but when i try the list {} in my console don't get the any value

Answer (score 0):

This question is to easy ... no?

```
    var holidays = [];

    calendario.getJobs().success(function(data){
        holidays=data[0];
    }); 

    $scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
      console.log(holidays);
    };
```

Comment: or not man...your example give me that 
Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]